# Keras Extremely High Loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, prediction, loss

I'm trying to predict price by characteristics.
I chose a pretty simple model, but it works very strange. Loss function is extremely high and I can't see where the problem is.

Here is my model:

```python
# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(62, input_dim = 62, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(31, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

That's how I prepare the data: (One-Hot and I split all data to train and test)

```python
df = encode_onehot(dataframe, cols=['Shape', 'Cut', 'Color', 'Clarity', 'Polish', 'Symmetry', 'Culet', '\tFluorescence'])

dataset = df.values
X = dataset[1:,4:66]
Y = dataset[1:,2]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

Finally, training:

```python
baseline_model().fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
scores = baseline_model().evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(baseline_model().summary())
```

And results are very sad:

```python
Epoch 1/10
149767/149767 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 104759338.0333     
Epoch 2/10
149767/149767 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 104594236.9627     
Epoch 3/10
149767/149767 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 104556662.2948
```

And it doesn't get better.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your input and output data look like?  Are the values of X one hot encoded as different integers or as vectors? Is Y one hot encoded to or not? It is not clear from the question

Comment: What's the range of `y_train`? Does it contain values larger than 10000 or so? It's not too strange to see a high loss if `y_train` contains some large values since you're using the mean **squared** error. Unless your model is extremely powerful or you have very strong features, the square of `y_true - y_pred` can be very large.

Comment: @gionni Values of X one hot encoded as vectors. Y is not hot encoded (cause it's just 'price')

Comment: Try more epochs. You could also try to normalize the values of y first (for example, to the range (0,1)) and then train your network.

Answer (score 10):

As @Yu-Yang said you are using mean squared error as loss function. I had this same problem before where the loss value will be very large, on changing the loss function to **mean_squared_logarithmic_error**, I got the desired result.

```
model %>% compile(
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr=0.0001),
loss = loss_mean_squared_logarithmic_error,
metrics = c("accuracy")
)
```

The loss value changed to

> Epoch 1/10
>   326981/326981 [==============================] - 17s - loss: 0.0048 - acc: 0.9896

Hope this finds useful !

Comment: He? I might get something wrong, but if you switch from MSE to a log error flavour, of course you get a lower value, but you should never compare the two values, since they are on a totally different scale. So if your model makes less (and/or smaller) prediction errors after training it with the loss "mean squared logarithmic error" than it does after training it with the MSE, it would be a good indicator that training with the log version is better, but otherwise it's just cosmetically showing smaller numbers which might make you more calm.

Comment: I guess that the log version mainly exists because it makes building the derivatives easier in combination with some activation functions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Normalize your dataset like preprocess step
2. As I can see, you are using a regression model, so with a regression model your loss will be completely different from what it would be if you used the model for classification
3. If you need classify. set the loss function in the likeness of **categorical_crossentropy** or another. And set activation func for last layer in your ml.

Best regards!