# Uncomprehensibly high loss value in regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression

Based on some research and experimentation, I'm trying to build a Keras regressor for a few select input attributes which I've run feature selection on to determine importance. Now, the loss is insanely high, along the lines of  loss: 70155460.5246 - mean_squared_error: 70155460.5246. Scaling the input matrix gets me a drop in accuracy to .98 which is still pretty high but makes some sort of sense. Scaling the output labels drops it to .20 but there are rapid upward and downward changes. On consulting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014723/keras-extremely-high-loss), changing the loss function with unscaled input/output values dropped loss to 2.0 but that is still pretty high. Would scaling the data make a difference? If not, what am I missing?
Data input:

```
mfcc.138       mfcc.139         rmse
```

---

```
7.4177908897   8.7774400711   -0.6439626217  
8.4525270462   7.3344416618    0.0017812252  
6.4304733276   6.186293602     1.766149044  
7.0980010033   7.032245636    1.2389802933  
7.7408356667   7.8073301315    0.2537946701  
8.5029277802   9.0334596634    1.3996462822  
7.3711028099   7.0261359215    0.0025191307  
6.5391979218   6.5412449837    0.2165737152  
7.1349864006   6.8030338287    2.1332325935  
6.0559616089   5.9253249168    1.0415539742  
6.9684019089   6.1278781891    0.5000677109  
4.9130806923   4.7042975426    4.3300828934
```

Data labels:

```
track.14  
---------- 
   514  
  1151  
 50135  
   361  
   193  
   612  
   171  
   173  
   943
```

Edit: Added code for reproduction

```
df=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
dataset=df.values
X=dataset[:,1:]
Y=dataset[:,0]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(33, input_dim=33))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape', 'cosine'])
history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=128, verbose=2)
```

This is the final code for the 2.0 loss but that's still 200% loss

Comment: The range of the output data should be the same range as the last activation function.

Comment: Any code you can share so that we can try to reproduce what you experience?

Comment: Just added the code!

Comment: Update: Scaling both the inputs and outputs produce a reasonable loss value. Any idea why?

Comment: Remember that if you scaled the data - you should compute metric values w.r.t. to rescaled values. So - you need to take model predictions, rescale them and then compare them using your metric.

Comment: You mean scale the data to be predicted, right? Because metric values are already being computed on the scaled training data.