# Keras loss constant

Tags: keras, loss-function

```
def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
        b = k.constant([1, 1, 1, 50, 50, 50], shape=[6, 1])
        return (k.mean(k.sqrt(k.dot(k.square(y_pred - y_true), b)))
```

This is our loss function and we got this result.

```
2800/2799 [==============================] - 245s - loss: 204.2003 - soft_acc: 0.5136 - val_loss: 64.3844 - val_soft_acc: 0.4648
```

We tried changing the learning rates and optimiser but the loss didn't improve

we refered to this link
[Keras Extremely High Loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014723/keras-extremely-high-loss)

```
epoch 1/200 ===========================] - 254s - loss: 4.0631 - rmse: 5.1670 - val_loss: 4.6882 - val_rmse: 4.7807
```

and added logarithmic error and got the above loss value. How to reduce the loss further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried normalising the data. It worked for me.

Comment: Loss reduced to 0.1223 now. I standardised the data and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: What's the accuracy of your model ?